# Изменить цвет ReadOnly свойств PropertyGrid, можно ли

Tags: winforms, vb.net, propertygrid

Хотелось бы контролировать стили свойств, которые помечены как `ReadOnly`.
По одной известной статье [ссылка](http://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/PropertyGridFAQ.xml) видно что название свойства серого цвета, у меня же все одинаково и не видно разницы, поле только для чтения или его можно редактировать...

Есть ли решение вопроса?

P.S. Вопрос актуален и для `CollectionEditor`

P.S.2 `DisabledItemForeColor` может поменять только цвет текста, а вот как поменять цвет фона...

Comment: Возможно, цвет зависит от текущей темы Виндоус. А так, смотрите свойство `DisabledItemForeColor` - именно оно отвечает за readonly свойство. Ну и другие свойства `*Color` исследуйте.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо, полезно, но этого маловато будет. Исследовал естественно, не нашел ничего что меняло бы не только цвет но и фон для заблокированных свойств.

Comment: Ну нет у ПропертиГрида стандартной возможности сделать это. Можно попытаться через рефлексию добраться до вложенных в него контролов. Или поискать сторонний похожий компонент.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А чем рефлексия не вариант решения задачи? На данном ресурсе вроде как и решаются задачи, так чтобы и учились люди сами и другим оставлялась информация. В чем проблема то в моем вопросе?

Comment: Для `CollectionEditor` я абсолютно уверен что без рефлексии тут не обойтись.

Comment: Reflection тут вряд ли поможет. Посмотрите как реализована отрисовка в GridEntry.PaintLabel (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyGridInternal/GridEntry.cs,774f30368b7117f6), там нет никакого специального свойства под цвет фона. Скорее надо "форкнуть" исходный код и заменить этот метод, но я не знаю, насколько он полный на Reference Source.